# PostgreSQL: Ignore/Load Null Dates via Select Substring

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am having trouble getting my fixed width Insert Into statement to handle a date field properly. I found some code on here to create an "is_date" function, but not sure how to make PostgreSQL pgAdminIII SQL Query window to recognize it.

> Error: function is_date(date) does not exist

What I found on another post on StackOverflow:

```
create or replace function is_date(s varchar) returns boolean as $$
begin
    perform s::date;
    return true;
exception when others then
    return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

What I wrote, with lots of help!

```
CREATE TABLE marc (statusdate date);
INSERT INTO marc (statusdate)
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN is_date(to_date(substring(data,228,60), 'DD/MON/YYYY')) = 1
             THEN to_date(substring(data,228,60), 'DD/MON/YYYY')
          ELSE NULL 
       END As statusdate
FROM marctemp;
```

Can anyone help tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `to_date()` which returns `date` while your `is_date()` expects a string. PostgreSQL doesn't do automatic conversions and in this case it would be silly to check if a date is a date since it can't be anything else. Remove the `to_date()` from inside the `is_date()` call.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you all you need to know: you are passing a `date` to a function that expects a `varchar`

```
CREATE TABLE marc (statusdate date);
INSERT INTO marc (statusdate)
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN is_date(substring(data,228,60)) = true
             THEN to_date(substring(data,228,60), 'DD/MON/YYYY')
          ELSE NULL 
       END As statusdate
FROM marctemp;
```

`boolean` values can be `true` or `false` so you need to compare the result of `is_date()` to that. `1` is not a boolean value.

You can actually leave out the `= true` completely, `when is_date(..) then ..` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Do I ask follow up here or edit original post? Getting a new/different error now.

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question. Don't change your initial question after every answer you get. You can link to this question in the new one.

Comment: Nope, no more error, read your post too quickly. Thank you again, that makes perfect sense and worked as designed. Very appreciative, I am so new to all this that each new task is like it's own research project.